# BigQuery select __TABLES__ from all tables within project?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Using BigQuery, is there a way I can select `__TABLES__` from every dataset within my project? I've tried `SELECT * FROM '*.__TABLES'` but that is not allowed within BigQuery. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Are you using Standard SQL or Legacy SQL?

Comment: @DevilingMaster Standard SQL.

Comment: From you question I understand that you do not have a common prefix for the name of all the tables you need to query into, is it true?

Comment: I'm trying to query all datasets within the project. The table names are irrelevant here.

Comment: Your goal is unclear, do you need a query to retrieve the names of all existing dataset (which is not possible)? Do you need to query the data on all the tables on all datasets of your project?

Comment: You just answered my question. I needed a query to get the names of all datasets, seems like I'm going to have to use the API.

Comment: Yes, you need to use the [datasets.list API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/list) in order to obtain all the existing datasets

Comment: it is possible through query, refer to the answer below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`__TABLES__` syntax is supported only for specific dataset and does not work across datasets

What you can do is something as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH ALL__TABLES__ AS (
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.1000_genomes.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.baseball.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.bls.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.census_bureau_usa.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.cloud_storage_geo_index.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.cms_codes.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.common_us.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.fec.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.genomics_cannabis.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.ghcn_m.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.irs_990.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.medicare.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.nlm_rxnorm.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.open_images.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.__TABLES__` 
)
SELECT *
FROM ALL__TABLES__
```

In this case you need to know in advance list of datasets, which you can easily do via [`Datasets: list API`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets/list) or using respective [bq ls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#listdatasets)

Please note: above approach will work only for datasets with data in same location. If you have datasets with data in different locations you will need to query them in two different queries

For example:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH ALL_EU__TABLES__ AS (
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.common_eu.__TABLES__` UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_eu.__TABLES__` 
)
SELECT *
FROM ALL_EU__TABLES__
```

Comment: This works fine, but do you the difference between __TABLES__ (that seems to undocumented) and INFORMATION_SCHEMA ?

Comment: I've reached rate limit trying to use the SQL for hundreds of datasets with thousands of tables.

Exceeded rate limits: too many concurrent dataset meta table reads per project for this project. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas

Answer (score 18):

You can use this SQL query to generate the list of dataset in your project:

```
select  string_agg(
      concat("select * from `[PROJECT ID].", schema_name, ".__TABLES__` ")
    , "union all \n"
)
from `[PROJECT ID]`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```

You will have this list:

```
select * from `[PROJECT ID].[DATASET ID 1].__TABLES__` union all 
select * from `[PROJECT ID].[DATASET ID 2].__TABLES__` union all 
select * from `[PROJECT ID].[DATASET ID 3].__TABLES__` union all 
select * from `[PROJECT ID].[DATASET ID 4].__TABLES__` 
...
```

Then put the list within this query:

```
SELECT 
    table_id
    ,DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time)) AS creation_date
    ,DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)) AS last_modified_date
    ,row_count
    ,size_bytes
    ,round(safe_divide(size_bytes, (1000*1000)),1) as size_mb
    ,round(safe_divide(size_bytes, (1000*1000*1000)),2) as size_gb
    ,CASE
        WHEN type = 1 THEN 'table'
        WHEN type = 2 THEN 'view'
        WHEN type = 3 THEN 'external'
        ELSE '?'
     END AS type
    ,TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time
    ,TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time
    ,FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m", TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)) as last_modified_month
    ,dataset_id
    ,project_id
FROM 
(   
    select * from `[PROJECT ID].[DATASET ID 1].__TABLES__` union all 
    select * from `[PROJECT ID].[DATASET ID 2].__TABLES__` union all 
    select * from `[PROJECT ID].[DATASET ID 3].__TABLES__` union all 
    select * from `[PROJECT ID].[DATASET ID 4].__TABLES__`
)
ORDER BY dataset_id, table_id asc
```

Answer (score 6):

I know that you ask for using BigQuery, but I did a Python Script to get this information that you are asking for, maybe it is can help another coders:

**Pip install:**

```
!pip install google-cloud
!pip install google-api-python-client
!pip install oauth2client
```

**Code:**

```
import subprocess
import sys
import threading

from google.cloud import bigquery

def _worker_query(project, dataset_id, results_scan ):
    query_str = 'SELECT * FROM `{}.{}.__TABLES__`'.format(project, dataset_id )
    QUERY = (query_str)
    query_job = client.query(QUERY)
    rows = query_job.result()
    count=0;
    for row in rows:
        count = count+1
    results_scan.append({'dataset_id':dataset_id, 'count':count})

def main_execute():


    project = 'bigquery-public-data'
    dataset = client.list_datasets(project)
    count = 0

    threads_project = []
    results_scan = []

    for d in dataset:
        t = threading.Thread(target=_worker_query, args=(project,d.dataset_id, results_scan))
        threads_project.append(t)
        t.start()

    for t in threads_project:
        t.join()

    total_count = 0
    for result in results_scan:
        print(result)
        total_count =  total_count + result['count']

    print('\n\nTOTAL TABLES: "{}"'.format(total_count))

JSON_FILE_NAME = 'sa_bq.json'
client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(JSON_FILE_NAME)
main_execute()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extend Mikhail Berlyant's answer and automatically generate the SQL with a single query.

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA lists all the datasets. You can use a WHILE loop to generate all of the UNION ALL statements dynamically, like so:

```
DECLARE schemas ARRAY<string>;
DECLARE query string;
DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE arrSize INT64;

SET schemas = ARRAY(select schema_name from <your_project>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA);
SET query = "SELECT * FROM (";
SET arrSize = ARRAY_LENGTH(schemas);

WHILE i < arrSize - 1 DO
  SET query = CONCAT(query, "SELECT '", schemas[OFFSET(i)], "', table_ID, row_count, size_bytes from <your project>.", schemas[OFFSET(i)], '.__TABLES__ UNION ALL ');
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;

SET query = CONCAT(query, "SELECT '", schemas[ORDINAL(arrSize)], "', table_ID, row_count, size_bytes from <your project>.", schemas[ORDINAL(arrSize)], '.__TABLES__` )');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
```

Comment: this was such a good addition! I went one further to parameterise this and ran into a small hiccup when loading the `schemas` variable, but SO came to the rescue and you can see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73041907/populate-an-array-in-bigquery-using-results-from-execute-immediate)

Answer (score 1):

Building on @mikhail-berlyant 's nice solution above it's now possible to take advantage of BigQuery's scripting features to automate gathering the list of dataset and retreiving table metadata. Simply replace the *_name variables to generate a view of metadata for all of your tables in a given project.

```
DECLARE project_name STRING;
DECLARE dataset_name STRING;
DECLARE table_name STRING;
DECLARE view_name STRING;
DECLARE generate_metadata_query_for_all_datasets STRING;
DECLARE retrieve_table_metadata STRING;
DECLARE persist_table_metadata STRING;
DECLARE create_table_metadata_view STRING;

SET project_name = "your-project";
SET dataset_name = "your-dataset";
SET table_name = "your-table";
SET view_name = "your-view";

SET generate_metadata_query_for_all_datasets = CONCAT("SELECT STRING_AGG( CONCAT(\"select * from `",project_name,".\", schema_name, \".__TABLES__` \"), \"union all \\n\" ) AS datasets FROM `",project_name,"`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA");
SET
  retrieve_table_metadata = generate_metadata_query_for_all_datasets;
SET create_table_metadata_view = CONCAT(
"""
 CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS
`""",project_name,".",dataset_name,".",view_name,"""`
AS
 SELECT
  project_id
  ,dataset_id
  ,table_id
  ,DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time)) AS created_date
  ,TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS created_at
  ,DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)) AS last_modified_date
  ,TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) AS last_modified_at
  ,row_count
  ,size_bytes
  ,round(safe_divide(size_bytes, (1000*1000)),1) as size_mb
  ,round(safe_divide(size_bytes, (1000*1000*1000)),2) as size_gb
  ,CASE
    WHEN type = 1 THEN 'native table'
    WHEN type = 2 THEN 'view'
    WHEN type = 3 THEN 'external table'
    ELSE 'unknown'
  END AS type
 FROM `""",project_name,".",dataset_name,".",table_name,"""`
 ORDER BY dataset_id, table_id asc""");
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE retrieve_table_metadata INTO persist_table_metadata;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT("CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `",project_name,".",dataset_name,".",table_name,"` AS (",persist_table_metadata,")");
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create_table_metadata_view;
```

After that you can query your new view.

```
    SELECT * FROM `[PROJECT ID].[DATASET ID].[VIEW NAME]`
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA instead of **TABLES**:

```
SELECT * FROM region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

Just replace region-us for the region where your datasets are.
If you have more than a region, you'll need to use UNION ALL.. but it's simpler than using UNION for all the datasets.

Or you can use a query to get all the unions all, like this:

```
With SelectTable AS (
SELECT 1 AS ID,'SELECT * FROM '|| table_schema ||'.__TABLES__ UNION ALL' AS SelectColumn FROM region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
GROUP BY table_schema
)
Select STRING_AGG(SelectColumn,'\n') FROM SelectTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

slight changes referring to > @Dinh Tran answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
project_name="abc-project-name"
echo -e "project_id,dataset_id,table_id,creation_time,last_modified_time,row_count,size_mb,size_gb,type,partiton,partition_expiration_days,cluster_key" > /tmp/bq_out.csv
for dataset in $(bq ls|tail -n +3); do
bq query --format=csv --use_legacy_sql=false '
SELECT
  t1.project_id as project_id,
  t1.dataset_id as dataset_id ,
  t1.table_id as table_id,
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(t1.creation_time) AS creation_time,
  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(t1.last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time,
  t1.row_count as row_count,
  round(safe_divide(t1.size_bytes, (1000*1000)),1) as size_mb,
  round(safe_divide(t1.size_bytes, (1000*1000*1000)),2) as size_gb,
  case
        when t1.type = 1 then "table"
        when t1.type = 2 then "view"
        when t1.type = 3 then "external"
        else "?"
     END AS type,
  case 
    when t2.ddl like "%PARTITION BY%" then "Yes" 
    else "No" 
  end as partiton,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(t2.ddl, r".*partition_expiration_days=([0-9-].*)") as partition_expiration_days,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(t2.ddl, r"CLUSTER BY(.*)") as cluster_key,
FROM `'"${project_name}"'.'"${dataset}"'.__TABLES__` as t1,`'"${project_name}"'.'"${dataset}"'.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` as t2
where t1.table_id=t2.table_name' | sed "1d" >> /tmp/bq_out.csv
done
```

Comment: change bq command in the 4th line to increase the number of results if you have many datasets (more than 50 in my case) `bq ls -n <max_results>`

Comment: as well the bq query command in the 5th line to `bq query -n <max_results>` if you have many tables

Answer (score 0):

I've reached rate limit trying to use the accepted answer in BigQuery SQL for hundreds of datasets with thousands of tables.

> Exceeded rate limits: too many concurrent dataset meta table reads per project for this project. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas

and had to use the API (Python 3.7):

requirements.txt:

```
google-cloud-bigquery==3.7.0
```

main.py:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Replace with your project ID
project_id = "your-project-id"

# Create a BigQuery client object
client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

# List all datasets in the project
datasets = list(client.list_datasets())

# Iterate through each dataset and list its tables
for dataset in datasets:
    print("Dataset: {}".format(dataset.dataset_id))
    tables = list(client.list_tables(dataset))
    for table in tables:
        print("\t{}".format(table.table_id))
```

Answer (score -1):

[Mikhail Berlyant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43458677/5675325)'s answer is very good. I would like to add there's a cleaner way to use in some cases.

So, if you have only one dataset, the tables are within the same dataset and they follow a pattern, you could query them using a [wildcard table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference).

Let's say you want to query the noaa_gsod dataset (its tables have the following names gsod1929, gsod1930, ... 2018, 2019), then simply use

```
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*`
```

This is going to match all tables in the noaa_gsod dataset that begin with the string gsod.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question by the OP. The question is to get all tables in a project.

Comment: @RenierBotha read what I wrote and you'll understand. You are assuming a project has always multiple datasets. Not true.