# Create View that will extract metadata information about dataset and table sizes in different environments

Tags: google-bigquery

We need to monitor table sizes in different environments.
Use Google metadata API to get the information for a given Project/Environment.
Need to create a view which will provide
1. What are all the datasets
2. What tables in each dataset
3. Table sizes
4. Dataset size

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery has such views for you already built-in: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro) is a series of views that provide access to metadata about datasets, tables, and views

For example, below returns metadata for all datasets in the default project

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

or 
for my_project

```
SELECT * FROM my_project.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
```

There are other such views for tables also

In addition, there is a meta table that can be used to get more info about tables in given dataset: `__TABLES__SUMMARY` and `__TABLES__`

```
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__`
```

For example:

```
SELECT table_id,
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time)) AS creation_date,
    DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time)) AS last_modified_date,
    row_count,
    size_bytes,
    CASE
        WHEN type = 1 THEN 'table'
        WHEN type = 2 THEN 'view'
        WHEN type = 3 THEN 'external'
        ELSE '?'
    END AS type,
    TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(creation_time) AS creation_time,
    TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time,
    dataset_id,
    project_id
FROM `project.dataset.__TABLES__`
```

Comment: so in above SQL you gave if I have to find information for all dataset in a project then I have to mention dataset name manually and the have to do union all or is there any better way, as because if a new dataset is created then again I have to manually add it

Comment: correct if you use `__TABLES__`. But you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views which do not have such "limitation" - see on top of my answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to automatize the query to check for every dataset in the project instead of adding them manually with UNION ALL, you can follow the advice given by @ZinkyZinky [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457651/bigquery-select-tables-from-all-tables-within-project) and create a query that generates the UNION ALL calls for every dataset.__TABLES_. I have not managed to use this solution fully automatically in BigQuery because I don’t find a way to execute a command generated as a string (That is what string_agg is creating). Anyhow, I have managed to develop the solution in Python, adding the generated string in the next query. You can find the code below. It also creates a new table and stores the results there:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

project_id = "wave27-sellbytel-bobeda"

# Construct a full Dataset object to send to the API.
dataset_id = "project_info"
dataset = bigquery.Dataset(".".join([project_id, dataset_id]))
dataset.location = "US"

# Send the dataset to the API for creation.
# Raises google.api_core.exceptions.Conflict if the Dataset already
# exists within the project.
dataset = client.create_dataset(dataset)  # API request
print("Created dataset {}.{}".format(client.project, dataset.dataset_id))

schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("dataset_id", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("table_id", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("size_bytes", "INTEGER", mode="REQUIRED"),
]

table_id = "table_info"

table = bigquery.Table(".".join([project_id, dataset_id, table_id]), schema=schema)
table = client.create_table(table)  # API request
print(
    "Created table {}.{}.{}".format(table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id)
)

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
# Set the destination table
table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
job_config.destination = table_ref

# QUERIES
# 1. Creating the UNION ALL list with the table information of each dataset
query = (
    r"SELECT string_agg(concat('SELECT * from `', schema_name, '.__TABLES__` '), 'union all \n') "
    r"from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA"
)

query_job = client.query(query, location="US")  # API request - starts the query
select_tables_from_all_datasets = ""
for row in query_job:
    select_tables_from_all_datasets += row[0]

# 2. Using the before mentioned list to create a table.
query = (
    "WITH ALL__TABLES__ AS ({})"
    "SELECT dataset_id, table_id, size_bytes FROM ALL__TABLES__;".format(select_tables_from_all_datasets)
)

query_job = client.query(query, location="US", job_config=job_config)  # job_config configures in which table the results will be stored.
for row in query_job:
    print row

print('Query results loaded to table {}'.format(table_ref.path))
```