# Populate an array in BigQuery using results from EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery's DynamicSQL to dynamically construct queries so that I can re-use code.

In my use case, I'm trying to build a re-usable SQL script to [get meta data of all tables in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457651/bigquery-select-tables-from-all-tables-within-project).

Where I'm getting stuck is trying to populate an array with the results of an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command.

Here is a simple snippet which illustrates my problem:

```
DECLARE project_name string;
DECLARE schema_query string;
DECLARE schemas ARRAY<string>;


SET project_name = 'my_project';

-- Get all the schemas in a project 
set schema_query = format("""
select schema_name from `%s.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`""", 
project_name
);

-- Add the schemas to an array
-- THIS COMMAND FAILS
set schemas = ARRAY(execute immediate schema_query)
```

One way to get the desired result, but which is not dynamic, is:

```
SET schemas = ARRAY(select schema_name from `my_project.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`);
```

So I want to be able to pass `project_name` as a parameter and then run the dynamic sql query, which returns a single column of type string, and save the results in an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
declare project string; 
declare schemas array<string>; 
set project = 'my_project';

execute immediate 'select array_agg(schema_name) from `' || project || '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`' into schemas;

select * from unnest(schemas);
```

Comment: Thank you @Mikhail ! The `array_agg` method combined with the `execute immediate .. into ..` approach worked.