# error of accessing bigQuery tables from jupyter notebook on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to access BigQuery datasets and tables from Jupyter notebooks on google cloud in order to search the tables with a specified column name.

I am using the code at [BigQuery select __TABLES__ from all tables within project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457651/bigquery-select-tables-from-all-tables-within-project), but no tables returned even though there was no error.

```
import subprocess
import sys
import threading

from google.cloud import bigquery

def _worker_query(project, dataset_id, results_scan ):
    query_str = 'SELECT * FROM `{}.{}.__TABLES__`'.format(project, dataset_id )
    QUERY = (query_str)
    query_job = client.query(QUERY)
    rows = query_job.result()
    count=0;
    for row in rows:
        count = count+1
    results_scan.append({'dataset_id':dataset_id, 'count':count})

def main_execute():


    project = The_Target_Project # which is not my billing project that 
                                 # I am using to run the notebook. Although I have 
                                 # tried my billing project, still no results 
                                 # returned even though no errors.

    dataset = client.list_datasets(project)
    count = 0

    threads_project = []
    results_scan = []

    for d in dataset:
        t = threading.Thread(target=_worker_query, args=(project,d.dataset_id, results_scan))
        threads_project.append(t)
        t.start()

    for t in threads_project:
        t.join()

    total_count = 0
    for result in results_scan:
        print(result)
        total_count =  total_count + result['count']

    print('\n\nTOTAL TABLES: "{}"'.format(total_count))

client = bigquery.Client() # I use my billing project by default
main_execute()
```

Do I need to specify a project or service account when I created the client ? I have used a project when creating a client but still no results returned.

Comment: I executed the above python code in my notebook and got the following output {'dataset_id': 'abcd', 'count': 15} is this your expected output?

Comment: @kiranmathew, yes, but I need to search some tables with some specified columns within 10+ projects and 500+ datasets and 10000+ tables on BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pandas as pd

column_name = 'Tree'
list1=[]
list2=[]
list_dataset=['prodect1_id','project2_id']
for data_set in list_dataset:
    client = bigquery.Client(project=data_set)
    datasets = list(client.list_datasets())  # Make an API request.
    project = client.project
    if datasets:
        for dataset in datasets:
            list1.append(dataset.dataset_id)
    else:
        print("{} project does not contain any datasets.".format(project))
    
    for i in list1:
        query = f''' SELECT table_name FROM `{data_set}.{i}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` WHERE column_name = "{column_name}"'''
        query_job = client.query(query).result()
        df = query_job.to_dataframe()
        if 0<len(df):
            print(f"For the project '{data_set}' , dataset '{i}' below tables contain the column name '{column_name}':")
            print(df)
    list1.clear()
print("\n\nCompleted")
```

Output:

[image]

NB: Before executing the above code make sure that the  jupyter notebook service account has enough permissions.